# Handling exceptions in MAUI

Tags: maui

Hi wondering if any one can give any suggestions on how debug or step into an unhandled exception .

When I try my code the app just crashes and I never hits the code that handles the unhandled or handled exception

https://gist.github.com/mattjohnsonpint/7b385b7a2da7059c4a16562bc5ddb3b7

then in maui program I have

```cs
MauiExceptions.UnhandledException += async (sender, args) =>
{
    Exception? exception = args.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    await LogException(exception);
};

throw new Exception("This is an unhandled exception.");
```

What Am I missing?

Comment: Where is the code that is causing the crash?  Have you added exception handling?  Have you stepped through it in the debugger?

Comment: What is your expectation? Not all exceptions can be caught or logged this way. Did you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: this is the problem when I try to step through the debugger it never gets there..  the expectation is that when an unhandled error occurs I can log it somewhere making a background http call somewhere I choose..  and to start with I just throw an exception in the maui program  throw new Exception("This is an unhandled exception.");  hope makes sense. if not do you know of any good example  . Many seems to use that example I put a link as a base and then hooking it as I shown you ..

Comment: Crashes may be occurring in the native layer and would not be caught by the managed handler.  Without seeing the actual code there is no way to help you.

Comment: you have all the code there is .. also same as this one too https://github.com/Redth/MauiExceptionsGottaCatchEmAll

Comment: "When I try my code the app just crashes" - where is **that code**?

Comment: HI for semplicity I use this github.com/Redth/MauiExceptionsGottaCatchEmAll  and debug and I have the same problem - break on all exception and never goes into it

Comment: Yes, we get it: you are hoping to catch an exception in a universal exception handler, and it isn't getting caught. Jason has described situations where this is unavoidable. You have to find, the hard way, what code of yours ran just before the internal exception. Breakpoints, commenting out some code, whatever it takes. What page was user on (or what page should have appeared) when it happened? What user action did they do? What code runs when they do that? It may help to do `try .. catch` around relevant view constructor, or button click handler. Once you find your code, add it to question.

Comment: Is there a better way rather put try catch in every method ? If this is the case well it’s rubbish and nightmare. I just want to make sure on what the approach should be

Comment: @developer9969 No. Hell no. This is beyond bad practice. One of the few rules, that no one will argue about, is "catch where you can handle it". But no code should run outside such block. (This is usually your commands in your VM.)

Comment: @H.A.H. things could go wrong in many places . Initialize - OnNavigated etc..  commands I am covered but anywhere else .. in short do you have a snippet or can share in few words what you do to handle errors in maui? As there isnt a concept of Global Exception handler

Comment: @developer9969 This is another nightmare. What do you think happens when this global exception handler gets your exception? The program will magically repair itself? New threads will be started and continue exactly from that place? The ones who got terminated will not mess up your system resources beyond repair? And lets not forget, that even if technically this is somehow possible, the business logic will suffer as well. And no tool can repair that. So yes. Everything should be managed.

Comment: So what you are saying really every method with potentially should be wrapped up with a try catch. What is my aim when an exception occurs go to a pretty error page telling u to restart the app basically and send a log.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. For this, you can post a new feature request [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have more chance of winning the lottery than the Maui Team implementing or even looking at this..